# getting error Undefined array key in php file with html forms

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I've got issues with sending data from a html list to a php file. here is my code:

```
`        <form method="post" action="file.php">
           field: <select type="text" name="name" > 
            <option value=”1” >No1 </option>
            <option value=”2” > No2</option>
            <option value=”3” >No3 </option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
           </form>
```

and this is code in php file which receives the value:

```
$var = $_POST["name"];
echo $var;
```

but I'm getting error  getting error Undefined array key "name".
would be thankful if anybody could help me with this issue.

Comment: The quotes around the option values are wrong, but other than that, this should work fine. _"and this is code in php file which receives the value"_ - are you perhaps requesting that file directly, independent from your form submission?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$var = isset($_POST["name"] ) ? $_POST["name"]: '';
```